# Can you apply a filter to Git Fetch?

Tags: git

I know that `git clone` now has a `--filter` option that allows you to filter out blob objects so that you get the commit and tree objects that define the structure of the directory tree without getting the file contents themselves.

But is there a way you can do the same for `git fetch`?  I'd like to get a list of all the filenames and their individual SHA1s for a commit on a remote server, without having to download all the files themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the same `--filter` options.  When `git clone` clones a repository, it's using the `git fetch` code to do it.  For some reason these are not documented  under [the `git fetch` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch), but they are still supported.

Comment: Thank-you - that would make a lot of sense!

Comment: I've reported the lack of documentation to the Git maintainers, and they've accepted it as a bug.

Comment: it is not fully the same, fetch does not work with --branch e.g.